# Replacing of HTML 5 codes with equivalent characters in Java

Tags: java, html, stringescapeutils

I'm trying to replace symbols of HTML 5 using  **StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4()**, but I still have a lot of symbols which haven't been replaced such as "&nbsp"," &amp". What will you recommend to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&nbsp` and `&amp` aren't entities. `&nbsp;` and `&amp;` are entities. If your string is really missing the `;` on them, that's why they're not being decoded.

I just checked (just to be thorough!), and `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4` **does** correctly decode `&nbsp;` and `&amp;`.

**The correct fix** is to fix whatever's giving you that string with the incomplete entities in it.

You could workaround it, also turning `&nbsp` and `&amp` into `\u00A0` and `&` using `String#replace` after using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4`:

```
// Ugly, technically-incorrect workaround (but we do these things sometimes)
String result =
    StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(sourceString)
    .replace("&nbsp", "\u00A0")
    .replace("&amp", "&");
```

...but it's not *correct*, because those aren't entities. Best to correct the string.